# RewriteRule for a language site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I did a little multi-language site and for have better SEO i tried to make a htaccess file with some rewrite rule.

The site is like this:

- base/index

  - base/folder1/index
  - base/folder2/index
  - base/folder3/index

---

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
###########
#   RewriteRule for errors
######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /errors/404.php [L]
###########
#   Skip for many file extension
######
RewriteRule ^\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
###########
#   Remove a trailing slash if needed 
######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
###########
#   SEO Rewrite
######
RewriteRule ^(en|it|fr|es|cn)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|it|fr|es|cn)/(folder1|folder2|folder3|folder4)$ $2/index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

There's anything that I can do or that i missed, for improve the site!?

Comment: What is the key area you are trying to improve with this question ?

Comment: I wanna just know if all I did in my htaccess was right and don't cause some SEO problem, like the flag…
sry… :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
```

The `^` means "beginning of the URI" and the `$` means the "end of the URI". So that pattern will only match URI's that look like: `http://example.com/.css`. Get rid of the `^`:

```
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
```

As for the trailing slash stuff, you should make sure you're not requesting a directory:

```
###########
#   Remove a trailing slash if needed 
######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Or turn off mod_dir. Mod_dir will automatically redirect any requests for directories that are missing the trailing slash to the same URL with the trailing slash. This does the opposite of your rule and it will cause a redirect loop. There's a good reason to leave mod_dir on, since it prevents information disclosure of directory contents even if you have an index file.

Comment: thx so much… i added your correction on my htacess. have you right before with a directory didn't work… thx
In ever here for future add thx!!!! <3 XD